# would be that = would seem that?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

*How I met my certain fate by Stewart Lee*

> I realised that the structural framing device for this show, a single
>   hour-long shaggy-dog story about anal investigation, religious
>   persecution and a blasphemous physical encounter with Jesus, **would
>   be that** the whole thing had been conceived as the joke that Joe
>   Pasquale could not steal.

The author writes about how Joe Pasquale used to steal jokes from other stand-up comics. That's why Lee constructed this "framing device", so that it would be certain that Pasquale wasn't the creator of Lee's joke.

Does **would be** mean **would seem** in this context? Thanks

Comment: No. Why would it be? Remove the subclause and read the phraise directly: "I realised that the structural framing device for this show would be that..."

Comment: @DanielRoseman Does "I realized that the structure would be" mean "I created this structure to be". I'm confused about this "realize". Thanks in advance

Comment: I think we'd need more context to be sure. Is this Lee himself speaking, describing how he created the show? In which case this presumably describes the end of a process where he was trying to work out how to structure it, and eventually came to the conclusion that he would use this framing device for whatever reason (comedy, to make a point, who knows).

Comment: Yes. Exactly :) It's him writing about how he created the show